# Two ways of evaluating $\int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}}$, giving discrepancy of a factor of $2$.

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

This is related to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940968/is-it-true-that-frac-delta-mathbfx-mathbfy-4-pi-mathbfx). Here I am evaluating (in the sense of distributions) for a vector $\mathbf{r} = (x,y,z)$
$$
\int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}} = \delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z) \ .
$$
At the same time, you can evaluate the above integral as
$$
\int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}} = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2 |\mathbf{r}|} \int_0^\infty dP \; P \sin(|\mathbf{r}| P) = - \frac{\delta'(|\mathbf{r}|)}{2\pi|\mathbf{r}|}
$$
where the last line uses the representation $\int_0^\infty \frac{dP}{\pi} P \sin( \alpha P) = - \delta'(\alpha)$ (which follows from $\int_0^\infty \frac{dP}{\pi} \cos( \alpha P) = \delta(\alpha)$). There is additionally the identity $\alpha \delta'(\alpha) = - \delta(\alpha)$ would imply that
$$
\cdots = \frac{\delta(|\mathbf{r}|)}{2\pi|\mathbf{r}|^2} = 2 \delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)
$$
where in the last line I have used the identity $\delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z) = \frac{\delta(|\mathbf{r}|)}{4\pi|\mathbf{r}|^2}$ which is equation (3.1.30) from Kanwal's book on distributions.

The above seems to say that $\delta(x)\delta(y) \delta(z) = 2 \delta(x)\delta(y) \delta(z)$, which is obviously wrong. Where am I making a mistake in my second way of computing?

**EDIT:** Note that the $3D$ Fourier transform of a rotationally invariant function $f(|\mathbf{p}|)$ is also rotationally invariant $F(|\mathbf{x}|)$,
$$
F(|\mathbf{x}|) = \int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} f(|\mathbf{p}|) e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}} =  \int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} f(|\mathbf{p}|) e^{i |\mathbf{r}| |\mathbf{p}| \cos\theta }
$$
where I have taken $z \to |\mathbf{r}|$ (free to do so by rotationally symmetry) and used spherical coordinates. From here the $\phi$ integral evaluates to $2\pi$, then doing the $\theta$ integral gives the $\propto \sin(|\mathbf{r}|P)/|\mathbf{r}|$ function in my formula above. I then use $f(|\mathbf{p}|) =1$ in the above.

Comment: Could you please show how you do this step?
$$\int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}} = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2 |\mathbf{r}|} \int_0^\infty dP \; P \sin(|\mathbf{r}| P)$$

Comment: @md2perpe Sure thing, I added an edit in the above. This is a standard result for rotationally invariant 3D Fourier transforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of the integral using spherical coordinates $$\int \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{p}}=\frac1{(2\pi)^2}\int_{\Bbb R^+}\int_{[0,\pi]} r^2\sin\theta\cdot e^{i|{\bf r}|P\cos\theta}\,d\theta\,dP=\frac{\delta(|{\bf r}|)}{2\pi|{\bf r}|^2}$$ is correct as are the identities you have used up to this point. However, it is important to note the lack of consensus in the proportionality constant of $|{\bf r}|^{-2}\delta(|{\bf r}|)$. For example,

- Kanwal (2004) defines $\delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z) = \dfrac{\delta(|\mathbf{r}|)}{4\pi|\mathbf{r}|^2}$ as you have stated, whereas
- Bracewell (1999) defines $^3\delta(x,y,z)=\dfrac{\delta(\rho)}{2\pi\rho^2}$ where $\rho=|{\bf r}|$ (see equation $(51)$ of [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)).

This primarily stems from the ill-defined nature of $x^{-\kappa}\delta(x)$ when $\kappa\ge1$ as discussed in [Delta function at the origin in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1951874/471884) and [Delta function of the Euclidean norm $\delta(|\mathbf x|)$ / in polar coordinates at origin $\delta(r)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3785712/471884) for polar coordinates representations.